# How to stop autocomplete and have normal tab with GNU readline library in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, libreadline

Right now, I'm running the following code in Python 2.7:

```
import readline as rl
rl.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi') #allow for arrow keys to be used
rl.set_completer()
raw_input()
```

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html), `rl.set_completer()` should remove the completer function, which I assumed would make tab work normally. But, the tab key just doesn't work at all.

I've also tried writing my own function and passing it in as a completer, but that didn't work either. (If someone could find a way of doing this that would make the tab key work normally, that would also suffice.)

How do I get the ability to use arrow keys with `raw_input`, but also have a normal tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
#allow for arrow keys to be used for raw_input.
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi') 

#set the tab key to make 4 spaces
readline.parse_and_bind("TAB: '    '")
```

For some reason, using `readline.parse_and_bind("TAB: '\t'")` caused Python to use way too much of the CPU and would just freeze the screen, so I had to switch it to use spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
rl.set_completer()
```

Removes completer function, but not the TAB binding. So tab is eaten, but nothing is done as the tab is passed to a "None function".

```
readline.parse_and_bind("TAB: '\t'")
```

results in infinite calls to the underlying completer function.

```
Read TAB -> Return TAB -> Read TAB …
```

Simplest method, at least when testing here, is to use the default *emacs* mode. If one only import `readline` without setting anything, `read_raw` works for arrow keys, and TAB result in TAB.

If that is not an option set a custom completer function. (Works the same for Python 3). This is also ***very likely*** the safer option.

If one press TAB the completer function is called. For *one* TAB key press the `state` argument starts at `0` and increment for each time function is called. As we return `TAB` it is important that we check that state is `0`. ***Else it will be called again and again.***

We also have to return the text, if any, else it is eaten by `readline`.

Simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import readline

def rl_tab_expander():
    def completer(txt, state):
        if state == 0:
            return txt + '\t'

    return completer

readline.set_completer(rl_tab_expander())
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')

while 1:
    inp = raw_input("$ ")
    if inp.strip() in ('exit', 'q', 'quit'):
        break
```

---

### Check on original test

You could use a log file. Here we look at what happens in the completer function if we return TAB or if we do not check `state` as per example above. We set a limit for `state` at 25, else it would continue ad infinity.

Run script in one console window and do a `tail -f /tmp/test-readline.log` in another.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import readline
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename = '/tmp/test-readline.log', level = logging.DEBUG)

def rl_tab_expander():
    def completer(txt, state):
        logging.debug("STATE: %2d TXT: %s", state, repr(txt))
        if state > 24:
            return None
        return txt + '\t'

    return completer

readline.set_completer(rl_tab_expander())
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')

while 1:
    inp = raw_input("$ ")
    if inp.strip() in ('exit', 'q', 'quit'):
        break
```

#### Result

```
DEBUG:root:STATE:         0 TXT: ''
DEBUG:root:STATE:         1 TXT: ''
DEBUG:root:STATE:         2 TXT: ''
...
DEBUG:root:STATE:        24 TXT: ''
DEBUG:root:STATE:        25 TXT: ''
```

Without limiting `state` level this would have continued until program was killed or if we press Ctrl+C and get lucky.